# How to send bulk emails in less time using php?

Tags: php, performance, email, phpmailer

I am sending bulk emails which are working but it's taking lots of time. I just sent the email only to 10 users and it takes around 2 min. I have to send the email more than 10000 users. What is the other way to send email faster? I am using PHPMailer. Would you help me in this?

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="process.php?key=createmail2" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="emailtemplate" placeholder="email" >
     <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="subject">
      <textarea name="mailbody" placeholder="mail body"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="addmail" value="Add mail" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php 
include('mail/PHPMailerConfig.php');
switch($_GET['key']) {
case 'createmail2':createmail2($conn);break;
default : redirect('index.php');
}

function createmail2(){
  $array=explode(",",$_POST['emailtemplate']);
  $arrlength = count($array);
  $subject=$_POST['subject'];
  $mailbody=$_POST['mailbody'];
  send($array,$arrlength, $subject, $mailbody);
}
 ?>
```

**PHPMailerConfig.php**

```
<?php 
require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');
function send($array,$arrlength, $subject, $mailbody){
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = '*****';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "abc@domain.com";
$mail->Password = "************";
$mail->setFrom('abc@domain.com', 'Teseting for email');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body =$mailbody;

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
 {
   $mail->addAddress($array[$x]);

       if (!$mail->send())
     {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $array[$x]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo .   '<br/>';
        break; //Abandon sending
     } 
       else 
     {
        echo "mail sent to : " . $array[$x] ;

     }
     $mail->clearAddresses();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're sending from gmail, you won't be able to send that many emails. They have a limit for about 10 or 20 i think. Use a service for that instead, like Amazon, MailChimp or similar.

Comment: No, I am not sending from Gmail.

Comment: That  I will update it.

Comment: `$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';` - According to your code, your're using gmails SMTP?

Comment: I update my code.

Comment: Then try with the real SMTP and see if it takes as long. I don't know of any SMTP's that can handle sending that many e-mails in one go, though. You basically need to send them in batches and it will take time.

Comment: FWIW I have no problem sending over 700,000 messages/hour with PHPMailer over SMTP to a nearby mail server, but then maybe I'm special :)

Comment: Mr.Synchro. How much time taken for 700,000 emails?

Answer (score 3):

There's [an example of how to send to a list from a database efficiently in the examples bundled with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). There's nothing inherently likely to get you blacklisted by using PHPMailer for sending large volumes, but you do need to tread carefully. Mandrill isn't magic - it's as vulnerable as anything else to being blocked if you send spam through it.

If you want to send 50 simultaneously from PHP, fire up multiple processes with the pcntl extension, but it won't actually help you very much as you'll be increasing overhead enormously. You can set `SMTPKeepAlive = true` in PHPMailer which will reduce overhead a lot (it avoids making a new connection for every message), but it still won't send simultaneous messages - nothing will. There isn't an option in SMTP to send multiple messages with different bodies simultaneously on the same connection.

Sending to a big list during a page load in a browser is very unreliable; use a cron script or background process to do your actual sending and just set it up through your web interface. One tip if you are waiting for a page load - call [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) early on so that it won't stop sending if your browser closes the connection - and beware the page refresh! If you want to send much faster, install a local mail server like postfix and use that to relay - it will be far faster and more reliable than sending directly.

Comment: Just don't forget to set up the correct DKIM and/or SPF-records in the DNS for the sender hostname if you're using your own SMTP-server, or many emails will likely bounce.

Comment: I am not using the database. I have more than 10000 emails with a comma. I will directly enter in the input field.But I will try your solution

Comment: The link you referenced is very slow in sending emails.